# How to block internet for everyone except for one single IP in Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-nsg

I have a requirement on Azure VM wherein I want to block internet access to all the IP's except for 1 single IP(which would be mine).

I'm able to block internet access for everyone by creating a Deny OutBound rule for everyone. However, when I'm creating an Allow rule with my public address with a higher priority, I'm still unable to access Internet. My understanding is that the first rule will block internet for everyone and the second rule(with higher priority) will only allow my IP to have internet access.

Can someone please check and let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm attaching the screenshot of my OutBound rules.

[image]

Comment: I am nit sure I understand what you want to accomplish. When logged in to the VM, the only address the VM should be able to access is your IP? In that case I would expect your ip to be listened as the destination, not the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outbound port rule section, the source address is the IP address of your Azure VM and destination is the target you want to reach, so add your IP address there (in the images below the target IP would be 142.250.185.110)

[image]

By the way, a nice tool to check your connectivity in Azure is "Network Watcher" - search for it in the Azure Portal, then go to "IP flow verify", enter your target VM and the destination (remote) target you want to reach. Network watcher tells you if the request would go through and if not, which rule is blocking it:

[image]

Comment: I did the changes as suggested by you. On the "Network Watcher" it is giving success "Access Allowed" However, when I'm trying to open any website on the VM by connecting via a RDP with the whitelisted IP, the internet is not working. Am I missing something more here? Do I need to do any entry in InBound rule also?
Note: As soon as I remove the DenyOutInternet rule, internet starts working which means the internet is working on the server

Comment: How do you open the websites on the VM? Do you type in the IP address in a browser? What happens when you execute "curl <yourwhitelistedip>" on the VM?

Comment: They are regular websites like `www.google.com` I'm not accessing any private or unusual traffic which has IP on it.